# User authorization Rails Admin + Rails API + React JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, rails-api

I made a custom authentication system for my app (Rails API backend + React front end) using the `bcript` and `knock` gems. (see tutorial: [here](https://ericlondon.com/2018/03/18/rails-5-api-and-react-frontend-jwt-token-authentication.html))

I added [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) to have a ready-to-use Admin interface, and I am now trying to manage authorization: I want only my users with the field `is_admin` set to `true` to be able to access the admin pages.

Hence I added this to my config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:

```
  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    if current_user.nil? || !current_user.is_admin
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
    end
  end
```

But when I try to access my admin pages in development I get the following error:

`NameError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard`
`undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #<RailsAdmin::MainController:0x007feeec371b98> Did you mean? _current_user`

using `_current_user` does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you `include Knock::Authenticable` in your ApplicationController? You have to include the helpers manually since Knock does not monkeypatch your controllers like Devise does.

Comment: Hi @max, thank you very much for your help ! yes, I did add `include Knock::Authenticable` in my application controller.

Comment: Oh yeah, you´re using `ActiveAdmin`. In that case you need to configure AA to use the correct method by setting `config.current_user_method = :current_user` in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb.`. https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#authentication

Comment: no I am using rails admin: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Try setting `config.current_user_method(&:current_user)` in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`.

Comment: Also you should `raise RailsAdmin::ActionNotAllowed` not `ActionController::RoutingError`. `404 - Not Found` is not the correct response.

Comment: Also using knock for your admin interface is not really going to work that well out of the box. Knock is stateless so clients need to send credentials for every request which means you need to use a SPA, while RailsAdmin is meant for "classical apps"  with server side rendering and session based auth.

Comment: adding `config.current_user_method(&:current_user)` gave me the same error output unfortunately :(. I know this isn't the correct response but I would like to raise 404 error so that people think there isn't any `/admin` page. 
Regarding Knock, it is the only tutorial I found to have a proper React + Rails authentication. If you know any better solution, I'll take it :)

Comment: I don't think just slapping RailsAdmin on is really going to do that much for you. You need to add a session based authentication system for the admin section like Warden/Devise/roll your own. This also requires adding back a bunch of the middleware which API apps skirt.

Comment: You could consider creating a seperate app for the admin interface which is a "classical" rails app with Devise/Warden for authentication and then splitting your models into a gem for reuse - but I would consider if creating your own React admin UI is actually less work in the end.